# Apple Earpod one-click/Double-Click not working on Sony Xperia Z1, Android 4.4.2 Kitkat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, headset, sony-xperia-z1

I have Sony Xperia Z1 loaded with Android 4.4.2 Kitkat. My Apple earpods were working fine on Android Jelly Bean ie one-click will pause/play & double-click will play next song (Volume controls don't work on Android), but after upgrade to Android 4.4.2 Kitkat the one-click doesn't pause/play & double-click doesn't play next song. Please help me out. I don't want to miss the awesome sound from my apple earpods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
hold the volume down button in earpod while inserting